# How can I configure log4net?

Tags: c#, logging, log4net-configuration

I use not from `app.config` configuration - I have a `log4net.config` file.

`App.Config` looks like that:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" 
                 type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
    </configSections>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="log4net.Config" value="log4net.config" />
        <add key="log4net.Config.Watch" value="false" />
    </appSettings>
<(configuration>
```

I added attribute to assembly like that:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "Log4Net.config", Watch = true)]
```

What am I doing wrong? Can you help to me please?

Comment: What kind of issue are you facing?

Comment: Actually, When i write appander in app.config with <log4net> tag there is no problem.Everything is okay.But when i was use external config file didnt logging.

Comment: please be clear and say what it is that is not happening